# Weasyprint export with PHP

Tags: php, python, shell, weasyprint

I try to execute in PHP a weasyprint command (it works in console) :

```
<?php
exec('/usr/local/bin/weasyprint --version 2>&1', $output);
print_r($output);
?>
```

but I keep getting these errors :

[image]

Is it even possible to call weasyprint this way?

Thanks

Comment: what about executing a batch script that does the command above? does that work?

Comment: Because it would be dynamic. For now I try to get the --version, but there would be some dynamic configs

Comment: im not a shell script guru, but i think you can pass arguments / parameters through it and then use it in the actual command

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'd have to try this and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I tried that but I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so to get rid of that Unknown locale error, here's the code you need to add before executing the weasyprint command.

```
<?php
$locale = 'en_US.utf-8';
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
?>
```